# Someone know a specific maximum principle...? [Solved]

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I need a maximum principle in unbounded domains: if $u$ is a solution, bounded in $\Omega$, satisfying

$$\Delta u+c(x)u=0, \ \ in \ \Omega,$$
$c\in L^\infty$,
$$u\leq0 \ \ in \ \Omega$$
$$u(x_0)=0, \ \ x_0\in\Omega$$
Then 
$$u\equiv0 \ \ in \ \Omega$$
Someone know where I can find this statement?

Comment: First you say $u$ is positive, then you say $u \le 0$.  So which is it?  If you mean $u \ge 0$ and $u \le 0$, well, then you shouldn't be surprised that $u \equiv 0$.

Comment: Im sorry, $u$ is only nonpositive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Hopf maximum principle to the operator $Lu = \Delta u - c^{-}u$, where $c^-$ denotes the negative part of $c$: The function $u$ satisfies (since $u\le 0$)
$$\Delta u - c^- u = -c^+u \ge 0$$
The Hopf maximum principle now asserts that $u$ cannot take on an interior maximum in any ball $B_R$ unless $u$ is constant there. In particular, you can take any ball around $x_0$ and see that $u=0$ on $B_R(x_0)$. But this holds for arbitrary $R>0$, so you're done.

Comment: Did you write $c=c^+-c^-$? But this is positive and the function $c$ could change the sign. I didn't understand this part.

Comment: Yes $c = c^+ - c^-$. And $c^- = \frac{|c|-c}2 \ge 0$ is the negative part of $c$. I think you'll have to explain in a bit more detail what exactly it is you didn't understand for me to be able to clarify things.

Comment: What is your definition of positive and negative part @SamL.? As far i know, $c^+=max(c,0)$, $c^-=min(c,0)$ and $c=c^++c^-$

Comment: I think your definition of $c^-$ is $c^-=max(-c,0)$. Am i right?

Comment: Where is using the limitation of the function c?

Comment: @Tomás: Yes, you are right. My definition is what I stated it in my comment: $c^- = \frac{|c|-c}{2} = \max(-c,0)$, so $c = c^+ - c^-$, $c^+, c^- \ge 0$. José: I used $c^+ \ge 0, u\le 0$ implies $c^+ u\le 0$ for the inequality on the RHS and $-c^- \le 0$ as well as its boundedness to be able to apply the Hopf maximum prinicple.

Comment: In the classical book of Trudinger (elliptic equations of second order), you can find a maximum principle in unbounded domains with $c\leq0$, so you dont need analysis locally in balls. Thank you for the demonstration.